# autowired object shows null even after @Configurable class

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, aspectj

I have this class in which I want to access ILibraryRepository's autowired object. I make an object of this class using new AddLibraryProcessor(). So I used @Configurable but still the output shows null.

```
@Configurable(autowire = Autowire.BY_TYPE)
public class AddLibraryProcessor implements ICommandProcessor<AddLibrary> {

    @Autowired
    ILibraryRepository repository;

    @Override
    public IWebApiResponse Process(AddLibrary command) throws DomainProcessException{
        System.out.println(repository);
        return null;
    }
}
```

my pom.xml looks like :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.springapp</groupId>
    <artifactId>xyzL</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>xyz</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.0.RELEASE</spring.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- aspectj -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Freemarker -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.freemarker</groupId>
            <artifactId>freemarker</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.14</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-json-org</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- DPCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Log4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>0.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.9-6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <finalName>NGL</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
                    <complianceLevel>1.7</complianceLevel>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <verbose>false</verbose>
                    <aspectLibraries>
                        <aspectLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                        </aspectLibrary>
                    </aspectLibraries>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>test-compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                        <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                        <version>1.7.4</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: did you used @Repository in repository Class.??

Comment: You did enable injection into non managed beans (e.g. with `@EnableSpringConfigured`)?

Comment: yeah it is,
@Repository
public class LibraryRepository extends Repository<Library> implements ILibraryRepository {}

Comment: @Markus: I dint get it...

Comment: You have to turn on `@Configurable` processing. You haven't shown any of your Spring configuration.

Comment: where to turn on @Configurable processing?

Comment: @FlorescentTicker what about component scan ??

Comment: <context:component-scan base-package="com.xyz"/>

Comment: yes but with that you must specify the packagestoscan in mySessionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

Injection into non managed springs by [`@Configurable`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Configurable.html) is not enabled by default. You have to enable this with e.g. adding [`@EnableSpringConfigured`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/aspectj/EnableSpringConfigured.html) to any [`@Configuration`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) annotated bean.

While reading [*8.8.1 Using AspectJ to dependency inject domain objects with Spring*](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) you will note a further requirement:

> For this to work the annotated types must be woven with the AspectJ weaver [..] or load-time weaving.

Comment: I dont seem to find any class with @Configuration annotation. Can I put some kind of xml in replacement of this annotation in my mvc-dispatcher.xml file?

Comment: @FlorescentTicker yes you can. I simply propagate the Java config approach. If you want to use xml, follow those links I gave you. It's all in the documentation.

Comment: "woven with the AspectJ weaver [..] or load-time weaving" ??

Comment: @FlorescentTicker Please read [8.8.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-atconfigurable) and follow those links. After reading ask what you didn't exactly not understand plus show what you've tried.

Comment: @Markus Malkusch ,adding EnableSpringConfigured to any Configuration annotated bean?
You mean so the class will have two annotations?

Comment: @yin03 yes, I mean that